# How to send notification when user clicks ad?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, click, ads

I am developing a system that shows advertisements on mobile devices. Our clients are allowed to use their custom HTML code for their advertisement. We would like to be notified when a user clicks this ad. I can wrap the user's code with some of my code. For example:

```
<div id="my-code" onclick="myFunction()">

<!-- users code -->
<a href="http://whatever.com/"> click me!</a>
<button onclick="someCode()" />

</div>
```

As you can see, the user can use javascript within their advertisements. When the ad is clicked I want to notifiy an external server, but I don't want to change the behavior of the ad. I have tried several approaches and failed to find a working one:

1. I cannot use ajax since ajax is restricted only to the domain of the
   page (advertisements are shown on external pages and cannot connect
   to our server). An alternative approach is the use of a tracking pixel, but:
2. A tracking pixel needs some time to be loaded. If users click an `<a>`
   tag then the pixel tracker added by `myFunction()` won't be loaded
   before switching to the new page. I could prevent propagation of the
   event, but:
3. The advertisement needs to get this click too. I tried to stop propagation of the event in javascript, load the pixel tracker, and then trigger the event again. Doesn't work - `<a>` tags are not clicked in this way - a click event triggered by javascript exists only on the javascript level.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You can still do a JSONP Cross Domain Call to your domain.

Comment: **http://json-p.org/** is the easiest option for cross domain ajax calls

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the main problem. If I call $.ajax(... contentType:'jsonp') within myFunction() and user clicks the <a> tag, then the page will be probably redirected the the new url before the asynchronous ajax request will be made. I wouldn't get any notification.

Comment: @user3323559 That's what `event.preventDefault()` is there for, allowing JavaScript to run it's conditions before placing the control back to browser, secondly if you were using jQuery - you certainly wouldn't use `onclick=""`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/burktelefon/audMu/)

```
<body>
    <div id="linkContainer">
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.icrc.org/eng/">Link</a>
    </div>

    <script type="application/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          function beforeLeave(){
            alert("Outa here!"); //Replace with function to do ajax-call to server
          }

          $('#linkContainer > a').on('click', function() {
            beforeLeave();
          });
        }); 
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was considering at some point, but it is no going work. The reason is because it is not possible to make synchronous ajax calls to external domains. Even jsonp content type doesn't help. Asynchronous call probably wouldn't be executed. This may be browser-specific, but since user is just leaving the page, browsers probably won't allow it to finish.

Comment: I obviously didn't read the question carefully enough. Sorry.